# how to display country and zone in opencart?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, opencart

I have created a registration page in admin section in **OpenCart**, in which we are asking details such as name, email, telephone, country, state/zone, password and many other things. Everything is working fine except **country** and **zone** form field. whenever I open the form I find one country always selected and nothing is displayed in zone field. This is first problem. When i choose another **country** then it loads **state/zone**, and if everything goes well, then the user gets registered. But if there is any error in form, then when it shows error on the page, state/zone value gets lost again. I have to reselect country and then zone is displayed. I have checked through **"echo"** that value of zone is transferred to this page but not shown selected in the drop down.this is my main problem.

this is the link to first image--
[image]

now this is the second image in which error messages are displayed---

[image]

Now someone please tell me what should i do?
I'm not an expert of opencart. i have just created this for the first time. I also don't have knowledge of jquery or javascript.
please tell me which part of code should I put here for getting solution.

thanks !!

this is **customer.tpl** template file

```
          <tr>
            <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_country; ?></td>
            <td><select name="country_id" onchange="country(this);">
                <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
                <?php foreach ($countries as $country) { ?>
                <?php if ($country['country_id'] == $country_id) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $country['name']; ?></option>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id']; ?>"><?php echo $country['name']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?>
              </select><?php if ($error_country) { ?>
              <span class="error"><?php echo $error_country; ?></span>
              <?php  } ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_zone; ?></td>
            <td><select name="zone_id">
              </select><?php if ($error_zone) { ?>
              <span class="error"><?php echo $error_zone; ?></span>
              <?php  } ?></td>
          </tr>

<!-- ... -->

<script type="text/javascript">
function country(element) {

if (element.value != '') {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=seller/customer/country&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&country_id=' + element.value,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
        $('select[name=\'country_id\']').after('<span class="wait">&nbsp;<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/loading.gif" alt="" /></span>');
    },
        complete: function() {
            $('.wait').remove();
        },          
        success: function(json) {


        html = '<option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>';

        if (json['zone'] != '') {
            for (i = 0; i < json['zone'].length; i++) {
                html += '<option value="' + json['zone'][i]['zone_id'] + '"';

                if (json['zone'][i]['zone_id'] == '<?php echo $zone_id; ?>') {
                    html += ' selected="selected"';
                }

                html += '>' + json['zone'][i]['name'] + '</option>';
            }
        } else {
            html += '<option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_none; ?></option>';
        }

        $('select[name=\'zone_id\']').html(html);
    },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
}

$('select[name$=\'[country_id]\']').trigger('change');
</script>
```

and this is **customer.php** controller file

```
<?php    
class ControllerSellerCustomer extends Controller { 
private $error = array();

public function index() {
    $this->language->load('seller/customer');

    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

    //$this->load->model('sale/customer');

    $this->getForm();
}

public function insert() {
    $this->language->load('seller/customer');

    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

    $this->load->model('seller/customer');

    if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validateForm()) {
        $this->model_seller_customer->addCustomer($this->request->post);

        $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

        $this->redirect($this->url->link('seller/customer', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, 'SSL'));

    }


    $this->getForm();
} 

protected function getForm() {

    $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

    $this->data['text_enabled'] = $this->language->get('text_enabled');
    $this->data['text_disabled'] = $this->language->get('text_disabled');
    $this->data['text_select'] = $this->language->get('text_select');
    $this->data['text_none'] = $this->language->get('text_none');
    $this->data['text_wait'] = $this->language->get('text_wait');
    $this->data['text_no_results'] = $this->language->get('text_no_results');

    $this->data['entry_description'] = $this->language->get('entry_description');
    $this->data['entry_firstname'] = $this->language->get('entry_firstname');
    $this->data['entry_email'] = $this->language->get('entry_email');
    $this->data['entry_telephone'] = $this->language->get('entry_telephone');
    $this->data['entry_business'] = $this->language->get('entry_business');
    $this->data['entry_password'] = $this->language->get('entry_password');
    $this->data['entry_confirm'] = $this->language->get('entry_confirm');
    $this->data['entry_status'] = $this->language->get('entry_status');
    $this->data['entry_company'] = $this->language->get('entry_company');
    $this->data['entry_company_id'] = $this->language->get('entry_company_id');
    $this->data['entry_address'] = $this->language->get('entry_address');
    $this->data['entry_city'] = $this->language->get('entry_city');
    $this->data['entry_zone'] = $this->language->get('entry_zone');
    $this->data['entry_country'] = $this->language->get('entry_country');

    $this->data['button_save'] = $this->language->get('button_save');
    $this->data['button_cancel'] = $this->language->get('button_cancel');

    $this->data['tab_general'] = $this->language->get('tab_general');

    $this->data['token'] = $this->session->data['token'];

    if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
        $this->data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
    } else {
        $this->data['error_warning'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->session->data['success'])) {
        $this->data['success'] = $this->session->data['success'];

        unset($this->session->data['success']);
    } else {
        $this->data['success'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['firstname'])) {
        $this->data['error_firstname'] = $this->error['firstname'];
    } else {
        $this->data['error_firstname'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['email'])) {
        $this->data['error_email'] = $this->error['email'];
    } else {
        $this->data['error_email'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['telephone'])) {
        $this->data['error_telephone'] = $this->error['telephone'];
    } else {
        $this->data['error_telephone'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['company'])) {
        $this->data['error_company'] = $this->error['company'];
    } else {
        $this->data['error_company'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['business'])) {
        $this->data['error_business'] = $this->error['business'];
    } else {
        $this->data['error_business'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['description'])) {
        $this->data['error_description'] = $this->error['description'];
    } else {
        $this->data['error_description'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['password'])) {
        $this->data['error_password'] = $this->error['password'];
    } else {
        $this->data['error_password'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['confirm'])) {
        $this->data['error_confirm'] = $this->error['confirm'];
    } else {
        $this->data['error_confirm'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['address'])) {
        $this->data['error_address'] = $this->error['address'];
    } else {
        $this->data['error_address'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['city'])) {
        $this->data['error_city'] = $this->error['city'];
    } else {
        $this->data['error_city'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['country'])) {
        $this->data['error_country'] = $this->error['country'];
    } else {
        $this->data['error_country'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['zone'])) {
        $this->data['error_zone'] = $this->error['zone'];
    } else {
        $this->data['error_zone'] = '';
    }

    $url = '';

    $this->data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

    $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text'      => $this->language->get('text_home'),
        'href'      => $this->url->link('common/home', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
        'separator' => false
    );

    $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text'      => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
        'href'      => $this->url->link('seller/customer', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, 'SSL'),
        'separator' => ' :: '
    );

    //SAVE and CANCEL Button
    $this->data['action'] = $this->url->link('seller/customer/insert', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, 'SSL');
    $this->data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('seller/customer', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, 'SSL');
    //SAVE and CANCEL Button

    //BUSINESS TYPE
    //Calling the model for displaying business type
    $this->load->model('seller/customer');
    $this->data['businesses'] = $this->model_seller_customer->getBusiness();
    //BUSINESS TYPE

    //print_r($this->data['businesses']);die;

    // For displaying values in form fields if an error occurs
    if (isset($this->request->post['firstname'])) {
        $this->data['firstname'] = $this->request->post['firstname'];
    } else {
        $this->data['firstname'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['email'])) {
        $this->data['email'] = $this->request->post['email'];
    } else {
        $this->data['email'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['telephone'])) {
        $this->data['telephone'] = $this->request->post['telephone'];
    } else {
        $this->data['telephone'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['company'])) {
        $this->data['company'] = $this->request->post['company'];
    } else {
        $this->data['company'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['business_id'])) {
        $this->data['business_id'] = $this->request->post['business_id'];
    } elseif (isset($this->session->data['business_id'])) {
        $this->data['business_id'] = $this->session->data['business_id'];       
    } else {    
        $this->data['business_id'] = $this->config->get('business_id');
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['description'])) { 
        $this->data['description'] = $this->request->post['description'];
    } else {
        $this->data['description'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['address'])) {
        $this->data['address'] = $this->request->post['address'];
    } else {
        $this->data['address'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['city'])) {
        $this->data['city'] = $this->request->post['city'];
    } else {
        $this->data['city'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['country_id'])) {
        $this->data['country_id'] = $this->request->post['country_id'];
    } elseif (isset($this->session->data['country_id'])) {
        $this->data['country_id'] = $this->session->data['country_id'];     
    } else {    
        $this->data['country_id'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['zone_id'])) {
        $this->data['zone_id'] = $this->request->post['zone_id'];
    } elseif (isset($this->session->data['zone_id'])) {
        $this->data['zone_id'] = $this->session->data['zone_id'];       
    } else {    
        $this->data['zone_id'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['password'])) { 
        $this->data['password'] = $this->request->post['password'];
    } else {
        $this->data['password'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['confirm'])) { 
        $this->data['confirm'] = $this->request->post['confirm'];
    } else {
        $this->data['confirm'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['status'])) {
        $this->data['status'] = $this->request->post['status'];
    } else {
        $this->data['status'] = 1;
    }

    $this->load->model('localisation/country');

    $this->data['countries'] = $this->model_localisation_country->getCountries();

    $this->template = 'seller/customer_form.tpl';
    $this->children = array(
        'common/header',
        'common/footer'
    );

    $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
}

protected function validateForm() { //echo "validating"; die;
    if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'seller/customer')) {
        $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
    }

    if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['firstname']) < 1) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['firstname']) > 32) || (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z ]+$/', $this->request->post['firstname']))) {
        $this->error['firstname'] = $this->language->get('error_firstname');
    }

    if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['description']) < 100) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['description']) > 1000)) {
        $this->error['description'] = $this->language->get('error_description');
    }

    if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['email']) > 96) || !preg_match('/^[^\@]+@.*\.[a-z]{2,6}$/i', $this->request->post['email'])) {
        $this->error['email'] = $this->language->get('error_email');
    }

    //For displaying error message if same email-id exist in database.
    $rv = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "seller_details WHERE email = '" . $this->request->post['email']."'"); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($rv);
    if ( !empty($row['email']) )
    {
       $this->error['email'] = $this->language->get('error_email_exist');
    }

    //For displaying error message if same telephone number exist in database.
    $rv = mysql_query("SELECT phone FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "seller_details WHERE phone = '" . $this->request->post['telephone']."'"); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($rv);
    if ( !empty($row['phone']) )
    {
       $this->error['telephone'] = $this->language->get('error_telephone_exist');
    }

    //For displaying error message if same store name exist in database.
    $rv = mysql_query("SELECT store_name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "seller_details WHERE store_name = '" . $this->request->post['company']."'"); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($rv);
    if ( !empty($row['store_name']) )
    {
       $this->error['company'] = $this->language->get('error_store_exist');
    }

    //$customer_info = $this->model_sale_customer->getCustomerByEmail($this->request->post['email']);

    if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['telephone']) < 10) || !preg_match('/[0-9]+/', $this->request->post['telephone'])) {
        $this->error['telephone'] = $this->language->get('error_telephone');
    }

    if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['company']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['company']) > 32)) {
        $this->error['company'] = $this->language->get('error_company');
    }

    //If no business_type is selected then error message is displayed.
     if ($this->request->post['business_id'] == '') {
        $this->error['business'] = $this->language->get('error_business');
    }

    if (!isset($this->request->post['zone_id']) || $this->request->post['zone_id'] == '') {
        $this->error['zone'] = $this->language->get('error_zone');
    }

    if ($this->request->post['password'] || (!isset($this->request->get['customer_id']))) {
        if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['password']) < 4) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['password']) > 20)) {
            $this->error['password'] = $this->language->get('error_password');
        }

        if ($this->request->post['password'] != $this->request->post['confirm']) {
            $this->error['confirm'] = $this->language->get('error_confirm');
        }
    }

    if ($this->error && !isset($this->error['warning'])) {
        $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_warning');
    }

    if (!$this->error) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}  

public function country() {//echo "country"; die;
    $json = array();

    $this->load->model('localisation/country');

    $country_info = $this->model_localisation_country->getCountry($this->request->get['country_id']);

    if ($country_info) {
        $this->load->model('localisation/zone');

        $json = array(
            'country_id'        => $country_info['country_id'],
            'name'              => $country_info['name'],
            'iso_code_2'        => $country_info['iso_code_2'],
            'iso_code_3'        => $country_info['iso_code_3'],
            'address_format'    => $country_info['address_format'],
            'zone'              => $this->model_localisation_zone->getZonesByCountryId($this->request->get['country_id']),
            'status'            => $country_info['status']      
        );
    }
    //print_r($json['zone'][0]['name']);die;
    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: Pardon my question, but *a registration page in admin section*??? What is it good for? Shall I be able to register to Your administration, then set the prices to 1 Rupiah and then buy all of the stuff for almost nothing? **Your images are useless, provide us with Your controller and template code.**

Comment: pardon my comment, but if you cannot answer a question, you should not make a comment which is useless, for just increasing your reputation.

Comment: You are new here, so I'll explain: **Comments are not increasing my reputation at all.** Comments are used for further questions and suggestion, which I both did: question is that I want to understand *why do You need this* (as if I find this useless I may decide not to loose more time and not to answer) and a suggestion is that I need to see the code You have written to identify the problem. So do not act like *I ate all the world's wisdom* as it is YOU who needs help and it is US who could provide it.

Comment: I may be new here. But I know how to respond to someone if I don't like anything. I could have used very easy words to ask a question from somebody. I would not have been so rude.


By the way through this form I'm creating a seller, who will then be added to the products according to the admin wish.That is my personal requirement. All I want is to solve the above problem. everything working fine, data gets inserted to the database if there is no error. but when there is error, it doesn't shows region/state selected. I need to change the country and then select back the same to get region.

Comment: I am sorry if my first comment seemed to be rude to You, I find nothing offensive on it. Maybe You are taking this too much personally. Anyway, I still insist on providing us with those codes...

Comment: It's ok !!
How should i post the codes. those codes are very long.

Comment: It is not a problem if the codes are long. Just make Your images smaller (only crop the meaningful area) and place the codes.

Comment: @shadyyx can u please answer the question as soon as possible ?

Answer (score 1):

I just made changes two changes in the template file --
1. HTML part
2. Ajax Script

1. HTML part is --

   ```
   <tr>
   <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_country; ?></td>
   <td><select name="country_id">
   <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
   <?php foreach ($countries as $country) { ?>
   <?php if ($country['country_id'] == $country_id) { ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $country['name']; ?></option>
   <?php } else { ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $country['country_id']; ?>"><?php echo $country['name']; ?></option>
   <?php } ?>
   <?php } ?>
   </select>
   <?php if ($error_country) { ?>
   <span class="error"><?php echo $error_country; ?></span>
   <?php } ?>
   </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_zone; ?></td>
   <td><select name="zone_id">
   <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
   </select>
   <?php if ($error_zone) { ?>
   <span class="error"><?php echo $error_zone; ?></span>
   <?php } ?></td>
   </tr>
   ```
2. Ajax part is --

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $('select[name=\'country_id\']').bind('change', function() {
   $.ajax({
       url: 'index.php?route=seller/customer/country&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&country_id=' + this.value,
       dataType: 'json',
       beforeSend: function() {
           $('select[name=\'country_id\']').after('<span class="wait">&nbsp;<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/loading.gif" alt="" /></span>');
       },
       complete: function() {
           $('.wait').remove();
       },          
       success: function(json) {
           if (json['postcode_required'] == '1') {
               $('#postcode-required').show();
           } else {
               $('#postcode-required').hide();
           }

           html = '<option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>';

           if (json['zone'] != '') {
               for (i = 0; i < json['zone'].length; i++) {
                   html += '<option value="' + json['zone'][i]['zone_id'] + '"';

                   if (json['zone'][i]['zone_id'] == '<?php echo $zone_id; ?>') {
                       html += ' selected="selected"';
                   }

                   html += '>' + json['zone'][i]['name'] + '</option>';
               }
           } else {
               html += '<option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_none; ?></option>';
           }

           $('select[name=\'zone_id\']').html(html);
       },
       error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
           alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
       }
   });
   });

   $('select[name=\'country_id\']').trigger('change');
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In  Your `getForm()` function find these lines:

```
if (isset($this->request->post['business_id'])) {
    $this->data['business_id'] = $this->request->post['business_id'];
} elseif (isset($this->session->data['business_id'])) {
    $this->data['business_id'] = $this->session->data['business_id'];       
} else {    
    $this->data['business_id'] = $this->config->get('business_id');
}

// few lines later

if (isset($this->request->post['country_id'])) {
    $this->data['country_id'] = $this->request->post['country_id'];
} elseif (isset($this->session->data['country_id'])) {
    $this->data['country_id'] = $this->session->data['country_id'];     
} else {    
    $this->data['country_id'] = '';
}

if (isset($this->request->post['zone_id'])) {
    $this->data['zone_id'] = $this->request->post['zone_id'];
} elseif (isset($this->session->data['zone_id'])) {
    $this->data['zone_id'] = $this->session->data['zone_id'];       
} else {    
    $this->data['zone_id'] = '';
}
```

and change them to

```
if (isset($this->request->post['business_id'])) {
    $this->data['business_id'] = $this->request->post['business_id'];      
} else {    
    $this->data['business_id'] = $this->config->get('business_id');
}

if (isset($this->request->post['country_id'])) {
    $this->data['country_id'] = $this->request->post['country_id'];   
} else {    
    $this->data['country_id'] = '';
}

if (isset($this->request->post['zone_id'])) {
    $this->data['zone_id'] = $this->request->post['zone_id']; 
} else {    
    $this->data['zone_id'] = '';
}
```

You are not working with session here but it may happen that the concrete values could be in session from some other form and this could mess things up.